# Integer fields appearing as #### in crystal report

Tags: .net, sql, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I have an integer field reading an integer value from database, however the value is appearing in the crystal report as ####, any body has an idea why is that happening? I checked the datatype, the values in the database, and they are all in the correct format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the field length where you are displaying the number is smaller as the size of the number itself. Example

```
1234567   <---- big number
|...|     <---- field length on report too small
```

Comment: @Hawk, I still need to wait 5 minutes to be able to mark the answer as correct, as a limit sit by Stack overflow